# ¿Cómo puedo ignorar o excluir datos según el valor de un campo en una Query SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-12c

```
select usr_login "USUARIO CONEXION", usr_udf_emplid "ID", usr.usr_emp_no "CEDULA",   
       usr.usr_emp_type "TIPO USUARIO", act_name "CAMPUS", ugp.ugp_rolename "ROL EMPRESARIAL", 
       usr.usr_udf_isempleado, usr.usr_udf_isprofesor,
       usr.usr_udf_isestudiantesregulares
       from usr, act, ugp, usg
       where usr_status = 'Active'
       and act.act_key=usr.act_key
       and usg.usr_key = usr.usr_key
       and ugp.ugp_key = usg.ugp_key 
       and usr.usr_login='ANGELA.ARAQUE'
       order by act_name;
```

--¿Cómo ignorar datos según ugp.ugp_rolename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar CASE.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN ugp.ugp_rolename= 'john_doe' THEN 'rol es john doe'
    WHEN ugp.ugp_rolename= 'derp' THEN 'rol es derp'
    ELSE ''
END AS "role name",  usr_udf_emplid as "ID"
FROM ...
```

Comment: Buen día Amigo

Comprendo tu punto, pero cómo podría hacer para que en la salida no apareciera por decir los campos 'rol es john doe' ?

Comment: Si te fijas, en el ELSE envía nada. Puedes hacer que devuelva algo según el valor de la fila, o que no devuelva nada, o bien que devuelva NULL poniendo ELSE NULL

Comment: Resuelto, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro. Un saludo.